# How to enable the security hub through cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-hub

I'm trying to enable the AWS Security Hub along with AWS Foundation Security Best Practice and CIS Benchmarking with Cloudformation template.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: 

Resources:
  SecurityHub:
    Type: "AWS::SecurityHub::Hub"
    Properties: {}
Parameters: {}
Metadata: {}
Conditions: {}
```

Is this Code correct or should I need to add more?

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong with the code? Any errors?

Comment: No, I got dought whether it can enable the Security Hub Checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-securityhub-hub.html) this seems correct. However, you don't need to define the `Parameters`, `Metadata` and `Conditions` keys if they are empty. I even think you can omit the `Properties` in the `SecurityHub` resource, but I am not sure and can't easily find a documentation link to corroborate.